# Evaluating $\int_0^1 \binom{n}{y} x^y(1-x)^{n-y}dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate the following?
$$\int_0^1 \binom{n}{y} x^y(1-x)^{n-y}dx$$ 
 Can you show me some detailed steps?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this the full question that you were given?

Comment: @KennyLau yes. what's wrong?

Comment: Because it would be easier if it was a summation where $y$ goes from $0$ to $n$

Comment: Since $n$ and $y$ are constants during the integration, the integrand is just a polynomial in $x$. What is your difficulty, where are you stuck, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I tried to integrate by part, but I did not succeed.

Comment: that is call beta function you find it anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming $y$ to be positive integer. For $s>0$ 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1(sx+1-x)^ndx=\int_0^1\sum_{y=0}^n\binom{n}{y}s^yx^y(1-x)^{n-y}dx=\sum_{y=0}^n\binom{n}{y}\left(\int_0^1x^y(1-x)^{n-y}dx\right) s^k,
\end{align*}
Substitute $u=sx+1-x$ $$\int_1^s\frac{u^n\ du}{s-1}=\frac1{n+1}\left(\frac{s^{n+1}-1}{s-1}\right)=\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^ns^k. $$ 
$$ \implies \frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^ns^k=\sum_{y=0}^n\binom{n}{y}\left(\int_0^1x^y(1-x)^{n-y}dx\right) s^k $$ Equation the coefficients, we get $$ \frac{1}{n+1}=\binom{n}{y}\left(\int_0^1x^y(1-x)^{n-y}dx\right) $$
Therefore, $$\int_0^1 \binom{n}{y} x^y(1-x)^{n-y}dx=\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Comment: please change $t$ to $s$